# Post/Upload file using Drupal Services Module without base64 (Using REST multipart/form-data )

Tags: media, files, 8, services

I am sure its possible in Drupal also.

Here is the reference for Java code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723429/use-rest-client-to-call-multipart-form-data-rest-web-service

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989937/form-post-through-rest-client-multipart-upload

But how can I implement for Drupal?

I want to upload/post a file to Drupal site using services module(without base64 encoding).

File uploading with base64 encode using Services module is working fine. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195165)

But I need to Post file without base64 encode.

I have tried following steps.But that's not working  (I am using [Chrome extension Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en))

**Step 1:** 
I have added Header like:

```
Cookie: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
X-CSRF-token: O7XJHc4DZOVTLSpgRQgF-XD5VD7QFkBpo7QIW8pfN7g
```

[image]

**Step 2:** 
Body parameters

```
file[file]: Choose files
file[filename]: myfilename.jpg
file[filepath]: public://my1.jpg
```

[image]

After following above steps I am getting error   "Missing data the file upload can not be completed"

I am using Drupal 7 and Services 3

Comment: May I ask why you want without base64 encoding?

Comment: Sometime encoding of base64 is not working for iOS and Android development. So I want to post file directly. Like we are doing in HTML form using enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: Regardless, I was getting that error because the file was too big and my colleague's instance of PHP/CGI couldn't take it (weird huh?)

Comment: DId you get this to work?

Comment: No, it was not working

Comment: parameters only file and filename. Set file to text and insert base64. X-CSRF-TOKEN and cookie and it works